# Best way to handle 404 error with redirect to homepage

Tags: php, html, apache

I've searched, read a lot, but still couldn't find a way, to achieve my goal. Now I even think it is impossible. Is it?

I want 404 errors to handled properly so I have `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` in the .htaccess file, and I want to send out the right header to search engines `header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found")` to forget that page, **also** I want to redirect my visitor to `/index.php?code=404` so I can inform him about that what he was looking for is not available, but still keep him on the site.

Now it seems everything is fine, until I want to redirect the user: then the server sends out a 302 message, which overwrites my previous 404 header, so while I can send the user to the desired place, I still can't tell the searchbots that the address is wrong.

If I add a `include("index.php?code=404")` after the header line it just won't work, the server says that file does not exist.

What should I do?

Comment: I've forgot to mention: as I searched on the topic, it raised an interesting question: what if my `index.php?code=404` page has something missing, like an icon for example. While my site generates the page, the icon will give a 404, which will redirect, which will generate a 404... so isn't there a chance that my original idea will generate some infinite loop?

Comment: Re your comment: yes, it will happily go into an infinite loop until you run out of space for access logfiles. Been there, done that. If the browser loads an image and gets HTML instead, it probably should not parse that HTML, but theory and practice are the same only in theory. Make liberal use of `data:` URIs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

    echo '<html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://www.mysite.com/index.php?code=404" />
            </head><body></body>
          </html>';


?>
```

I'm using a `meta` redirect because otherwise you get an error that headers have already been sent.

I tested this on localhost using Fiddler, and got a proper 404 response, and then was correctly redirected to a different page successfully.

Answer (score 5):

Another suggestion I would advise modifying the .htaccess to handle the 404.

adding something like  :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

to your .htaccess will handle things very nicely for you.

You can place the 404 error template anywhere you want. For example you could place all error messages in a folder called 'errors'

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

Handles things nicely and other error messages of course.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the `include("index.php")` onto your 404 page without the code parameter; then within your index.php include a section that will check the URL of the current page. So if the page URL contains `404.html`, include the error message, otherwise show the main index as normal.