# php how to redirect when page not found or access denied, or no permission

Tags: php, redirect, permissions, user-defined-functions

How can I make my website to redirect to a particular page when user attempts to folder or files that are not allowed or when they access not existing web page?
I think it is done using some kind of server side scripts, please help me to find it.

Comment: this might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501985/best-way-to-handle-404-error-with-redirect-to-homepage

Answer (score 3):

If you want **to prevent users from certain content use `403 Forbidden` header**. Not `404`. You might want to use `404` to fool the user, but later when something goes wrong it'll be very difficult do debug. Also this is not standard practice.

You can throw a `403 Forbidden` error  using htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(secret_dir1|secret_dir2|secret/file.php) - [F, L]
```

On PHP end you should invoke a header if some one is trying to get an unauthorized access.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden");
```

Comment: *" to prevent users from certain content use 403 Forbidden header..."* - Yes, that's why I am here. Where is the PHP code to place between the `<?php` and `?>`? My attempts to produce the 403 are failing.

Comment: @jww `<?php header("HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden"); ?>` should be executed before you send any output

Answer (score 1):

that should be done in .htaccess file, add this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 index.php // it could be any file/page
```

Check this link out: http://www.awesomephp.nl/htaccess/custom-error-pages